# How to combine 2 different models with a 'Model in the middle'?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm creating a HTML table which will show available stock of a list of products in different warehouses. But a product is (of course) not directly bound to a warehouse. This is bound with a third model stock. The idea is that I create the table and in the left most column you'll have the list of products, with vertical columns with the warehouse stock.

The problem comes when not all warehouses are able to have this product. So they won't appear in the database. Example: Product X will never go to Warehouse A so the Stock record with those respectively won't be created.

I've already successfully tried something and it does work, but I feel like it's really bad code. Definitely since Django Templates are supposed to be as easy as possible. This is not:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(....

class Warehouse(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(....

class Stock(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product...
    warehouse = models.ForeignKey(Warehouse...
    quantity = models.CharField(....

@register.simple_tag # I'll get to this
def get_k_v(l, key, v):
    try:
        return l.get(**{key: v})
    except:
        return None
```

What I do now is, I loop over the Products and inside of each row loop over all the warehouses using a callback to a function, if it exists I show the quantity if it doesn't the cell will become gray (for now, might change).

Visualization:

```
{% for product in products %}
    <tr>
         <td>{{ product }}</td>
         {% for warehouse in warehouses %}
              {% get_k_v product.stock_set 'warehouse' warehouse as ware_prod %}
              {% if ware_prod %} ...
```

As you might imagine and possibly agree with me, even though this works it looks bad and I'd say it's really bad performance wise. We've got 300+ products in a database and it already takes a couple of seconds to load with 10 warehouses.

As I'm not that advanced (yet) with Django, I wonder on how I could improve this.

**EDIT:**
I've been trying to solve this and created a query which outputs the requested result. It looks like this:

```sql
SELECT products.id, products.name, warehouses.id, warehouses.name, stock.quantity
FROM products CROSS JOIN warehouses
LEFT JOIN stock ON stock.product_id = products.id AND stock.warehouse_id = warehouses.id
```

Is there a way to implement this using Django's ORM? Or like an alternative query that produces the same or very similar result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use raw SQL:

```
from django.db import connection
query='SELECT app_product.id, app_product.name, app_warehouse.id, app_warehouse.name, app_stock.quantity \
       FROM app_product CROSS JOIN app_warehouse \
       LEFT JOIN app_stock ON app_stock.product_id = app_product.id AND app_stock.warehouse_id = app_warehouse.id'
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
   cursor.execute(query)
   result_table = cursor.fetchall()
```

More information about raw SQL is here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly